# AB testing config applied but firebase console show 0 users

Tags: firebase, ab-testing, firebase-remote-config

I've configured firebase ab-testing. Everything works fine except there is no impact user on console.

Actually, I can see UI and log show ab-testing is applied.
Moreover, by checking the other StackoverFlow topic, activateFetched also invoked after fetch successfully.

Moreover, I've referenced

1. [Firebase Remote Config A/B testing shows no results after 24 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311141/firebase-remote-config-a-b-testing-shows-no-results-after-24-hours)
2. [Firebase Remote Config results on initial request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48629338/firebase-remote-config-results-on-initial-request)
3. [Remote Config A/B Test does not provide results on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47348836/remote-config-a-b-test-does-not-provide-results-on-ios?rq=1)

But those are no work on my case.
Is there anything miss or any other need to check so that client can response AB testing result to firebase console.

Thanks for your help first.

Code snippet:

```
    [FIRApp configure];

    FIRRemoteConfigSettings* configSettings = [[remoteConfig configSettings] initWithDeveloperModeEnabled:YES];
    [[FIRRemoteConfig remoteConfig] setConfigSettings:configSettings];

    [[FIRRemoteConfig remoteConfig] fetchWithExpirationDuration:duration completionHandler:^(FIRRemoteConfigFetchStatus status, NSError *error) {

        if (status == FIRRemoteConfigFetchStatusSuccess) {
            BOOL configFound = [[FIRRemoteConfig remoteConfig]  activateFetched];
```

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this particular problem? I have exactly the same issue. The AB test is for sure working as I can see that I get different variations from the Firebase, testing with draft works too but I don't have any data yet after 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things to check or take note of:

- Make sure you're using and have deployed the latest Remote Config SDK.  Earlier versions don't work with A/B test experiments.
- Be sure to verify your experiment on a test device by following the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ab-testing/abtest-config#validate_your_experiment_on_a_test_device)
- It can take a couple days for data to come in for your experiment.

Answer (score 1):

Please call the functions in the following order:

1. `fetch()`
2. Call `activatefetched()` in the completion handler of `fetch()`.
3. Fire activation event. If you need to call activation event immediately after `activatefetched()`, add a time delay of a few seconds. This is because `activatefetched()` process asynchronously and hence the function may not execute completely, before the activation event is fired.

Once done, test a running experiment on test device. In the debug logs search with string "exp_X" where 'X' is the experiment Id. You will find the experiment Id in the URL of the experiment. If you find the experiment ID in the debug logs while executing the code on test device, it means the device was covered in experiment.
Also if the experiment setup is correct, the running experiment will show 1 active experiment user in the console.